# Racing profitably with expensive cars in Real Racing 3

Tags: real-racing-3

I've completed about 50% of Real Racing 3, own 29 cars and my driver level is 72. As I progress towards the series with the really slick (and expensive) cars, I'm starting to notice I'm making hardly enough money to cover repairs after race. Pushing from the 22nd position to the podium in about three laps requires some rather brutal driving, and even with somewhat clean racing my cars seem to decay faster than most isotopes of uranium. Winning R$8,500 from a race and repairing the car for R$8,400 gets rather frustrating fast.

How can I turn this around and start making money to afford even faster cars? Should I just keep replaying the races that net more than R$10,000? Or are there some hidden rewards besides the tiny bonus for 100% series completion?

Comment: I think the game was specifically designed to play like this, in the hopes you'll pay real money to bypass it.

Comment: That's my hunch too. I'm hoping to be proved wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thankfully, the latest "Prestige" update seems to fix this issue. Repair costs for damage during the race are now deducted from the new "clean race bonus", preventing them from eating away your whole reward. Also, there is now only one "condition" meter instead of separate ones for oil, engine, brakes and so on, considerably capping down the maximum R$ you're going to have to pay for servicing your ride.

So, how to race profitably with higher tier cars? **Install the latest update.**

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings and set your assist braking to medium. A couple of upgrades usually help. Avoid going off track as you will get damage. Do not repair your brakes. It's a waist of R$.

Comment: I already drive with all assists off, because even the medium brake assist takes away way too much control of the car. Why is repairing brakes a waste? Shorter braking distances are crucial to winning a race, especially on tracks like Mount Panorama and Hockenheim that have tight turns after very long straights.

Answer (score 0):

To earn money, replay previous races.

The most profitable way for me is:

Fully upgrade the best car of an older, already completed series. 
Then take on one of the endurance races, win them and keep driving after you've reached the distance target.

It's easier than in most other race types to keep to the track and earn a clean race bonus. Also the money you earn is related to the distance you achieve, you can get higher payouts then in most other categories. Try to combine it with the daily race bonus.

Higher leagues and later races will earn more money, but will get more difficult to win and cars/upgrades will be more expensive, so you have to balance that.

Or, as previously commented, pay real money.

Answer (score 0):

As a level 52 player I have found that the first race of the day ( if you've played every day and get the 100 percent bonus) should be one that pays 10,000 points and you usually win ( with me that would be the ford cobra on the Indy speedway). Its always nice to start the day with at least a 24,000 point award ( don't forget to check on the managers free offer to help by Doubling that amount).

Never spend your gold on repairs,managers, mechanics or fame, its a waste.

Drive dirty to get into the leaders pack when beginning any race.  Turn off the driving helpers when you start the race, then when your in the lead position, turn your helpers on again and take a Sunday drive to the finish.  Don't pay for anything!  If you need money go back and drive the old races again.  They still pay the same and you can never loose your best place finish.

Answer (score -1):

- daily bonus %100
- Agent x2 $115
- 10.000 fame in GT1 grand tour/superfly intercontinental showdown round 2